Get preferred `hourCycle` of user's locale
How do I obtain the preferred hourCycle of the user's current locale? I've tried a few locales ((new Intl.Locale('en-US')).hourCycle) in both Firefox 131 and Chrome 129, but both return undefined.


console.log(new Intl.Locale('en-US').hourCycle);




It looks like you have a misconception about the hourCycle property. If you neither set a hourCycle via the locale identifier nor via the hourCycle option, it will always be undefined. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Locale/hourCycle#description

Intl.Locale() only returns this information if it's passed via the locale tag or the hourCycle option. To get the hourCycle even if neither of these apply, you need to use Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions() instead (note that you need to specify the timeStyle option):


const dateTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { timeStyle: 'long' });
const { hourCycle } = dateTimeFormat.resolvedOptions();
console.log(hourCycle);



